# How to synchronize the database upon team work on Drupal 8 project?

Tags: 8, database

For example, there is being written a big project on Drupal 8 by several developers. They use Git for team working.

The first developer is creating some node types and adding some test nodes.
At the same time the second developer is creating some taxonomy vocabularies and adding several taxonomy terms.

At the same time the third developer is setting up search indexes for Search API.

After it they need to synchronize the database for continuing work.

I suppose that commiting, pushing and manually merging SQL dumps is not good idea.

Could you share your experience, how is the best way to synchronize the database after work ? Are there any good tools for it ?

Comment: Content deployment is a sticky and complicated issue in Drupal, always has been; D8 made strides forward but there's still no perfect solution out there. The best effort so far (IMO) is the Deploy module + RELAXed web services, but even that's not quite ready for prime time yet. I'm afraid it's too big of a subject to tackle here in a single question (you can probably tell that yourself as you're asking for off-topic things like people to share experiences or recommend tools, rather than asking for an answer to a specific question). Don't forget that starting a bounty on the duplicate is...

Comment: ...always an option, if you think that making the topic a bit more visible might get it some more interest or answers.

Comment: @Clive – Deploy in combination with RELAXed actually would make quite an interesting answer in the other issue. Would you mind extending your comment over there?

Comment: @leymannx I thought about it, but it was so buggy when I tried to install it the other day - I didn't want to send people off on the same frustrating journey :) It required manual intervention even to get the deploy module installed at all, and even once I'd managed that it didn't actually do what it said it would after ~4 hours of messing around. I can see from the code what it's trying to do, and it'll be awesome once it's finished, but right now I'm not sure it's a reasonable answer to the question